# How do I add an ISBN to Calibre ebook?

Tags: calibre, isbn

[According to the Calibre website](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/metadata.html):

> Click the book you want to edit and then click the Edit metadata button or press the E key. A dialog opens that allows you to edit all aspects of the metadata. It has various features to make editing faster and more efficient. A list of the commonly used tips:
>
> - The ISBN box will have a red background if you enter an invalid ISBN. It will be green for valid ISBNs

I see no ISBN box, red, green or otherwise in the edit metadata dialogue.

[On another Calibre page I see](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/template_lang.html):

> you might want to display the ISBN, a field that calibre does not display.

… followed by something about "simply hover your mouse over the column header" in the Calibre template language, which I cannot find.

So, how do I add an ISBN (which I have) to the publication I need to convert to ebook?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The field for the ISBN is labeled "Ids:" and is located between "Tags" and "Dates". It allows you to enter ID types other than ISBNs.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a plugin called [Extract ISBN](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=126727) that scans the selected ebooks and, if it finds a valid ISBN code inside, updates the proper field automatically.